# Cannot create a csv file from a datatable and dataview

Tags: vb.net, datatables, export-to-csv, dataview

I have code that produces a csv file (with headers) that contain fields identifying pixel locations of points of interest in selected images. Unfortunately, there are occasional duplicates that cause issues later in my production process. My plan to solve this is to open the csv file in the midst of the application, read the data into a data table, sort the data table with a data view using 4 sort keys (I am using the default Column1, Column2 etc) as i cannot figure out ho to use the real column header names contained in the first row. I have attempted to write the resulting rows to a new file, and I get the correct number of rows in the output csv file, but the data in the row is missing and i get a text string ' System.Data.DataRowView, not the 12 fields i was expecting.

In the code, my most recent attempt is to create a writeOutPutLine containing the concatenated contents of the row, in my desired sort order.

I have attempted to use CSVHelper with no success, and also tried about 10 other code sets posted on the various web sites.

Here is my code

Sub New_Csv_Sort()

```
    Dim linecount As Integer = 1
    Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable 
    Dim dgv As DataGridView = New DataGridView
    Dim TextLine As String = ""
    Dim SplitLine() As String
    Dim objReader As New System.IO.StreamReader(TargetFileName, Encoding.ASCII)
    Dim ColumnCount As Integer = 0

    For ColumnCount = 1 To 13 Step 1
        dt.Columns.Add()
    Next

    Dim firstline As Boolean = True


    Do While objReader.Peek() <> -1
        TextLine = objReader.ReadLine()
        SplitLine = Split(TextLine, ",")
        dt.Rows.Add(SplitLine)
        If FirstTime = True Then 


' Here I was trying to use the first line to set the column labels but no joy
            ' For ColumnCount = 1 To 12 Step 1
            ' dt.datacolumn.
            ' Next
        End If
    Loop

    ' This next is commentted out in the sort statement because I could not get the column names to be recognised

'.Sort = "Datum ASC, Picture ASC, Y_Loc ASC, X_Loc, ASC"

    Dim dv As New DataView(dt) With {
    .Sort = "Column5 ASC, Column1 ASC, Column12 ASC, Column11 ASC"
    }
    FileOpen(SortedTargetFileNumber, SortedTargetFileName, OpenMode.Output)
```

'I have looked that the data and it is read in correctly
But my output line is trash!

```
    For Each Rowview As DataRowView In dv
        'WriteOutPutLine = dv.row
        For Each DataColumn In dt.Columns
            WriteOutPutLine = WriteOutPutLine & Row[col].tostring() & ","
        Next
        WriteOutPutLine = Rowview.ToString
        PrintLine(SortedTargetFileNumber, WriteOutPutLine)
        linecount = linecount + 1
    Next
    FileClose(SortedTargetFileNumber)
    MsgBox("Sorted Lines = " & linecount)


End Sub
```

Comment: The line `WriteOutPutLine = Rowview.ToString` wipes out all the work the `For` loop just before it did. Please remove that line and see if it now works; if not, then if you show us an example of a trash output line that might help us see what is wrong.

Comment: Thanks for your sharp eyes on the over-write - I probably would have noticed this at the start of the next ice age! But this did not give the contents of the cells in the row, so I used Patels code instead. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

```
 Sub New_Csv_Sort()
    Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable
    Dim TextLine As String = ""
    Dim SplitLine() As String
    Dim objReader As New System.IO.StreamReader(TargetFileName, Encoding.ASCII)
    Dim ColumnCount As Integer = 0

    'Create columns for the data - 
    For ColumnCount = 1 To 13 Step 1
        dt.Columns.Add()
    Next

    'Load the datatable
    Do While objReader.Peek() <> -1
        TextLine = objReader.ReadLine()
        SplitLine = Split(TextLine, ",")
        dt.Rows.Add(SplitLine)
    Loop

    'This is the sort order based on the header titles, but is translated the the default column name

    '.Sort = "Datum ASC, Picture ASC, Y_Loc ASC, X_Loc ASC"

    Dim dv As New DataView(dt) With {
    .Sort = "Column5 ASC, Column1 ASC, Column12 ASC, Column11 ASC"
    }
    'Open the output file

    FileOpen(SortedTargetFileNumber, SortedTargetFileName, OpenMode.Output)

    'Create a string of all the rows in the dataview separated by commas

    Dim DataLine As String = ""
    For Each r As DataRowView In dv
        DataLine &= String.Join(",", r.Row.ItemArray) & Environment.NewLine
    Next
    ' Write the data to a file
    WriteOutPutLine = DataLine
    PrintLine(SortedTargetFileNumber, WriteOutPutLine)
    FileClose(SortedTargetFileNumber)
    ' and we are done
    End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

try this function

```
Private Function ConvertToCSV(ByVal dt As DataTable) As String
    Dim sb As New Text.StringBuilder()
    For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
        sb.AppendLine(String.Join(",", (From i As Object In row.ItemArray Select i.ToString().Replace("""", """""").Replace(",", "\,").Replace(Environment.NewLine, "\" & Environment.NewLine).Replace("\", "\\")).ToArray()))
    Next

    Return sb.ToString()
End Function
```

Comment: @Rfrank Please see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: This worked for the writing the original data table but did not export the dataview(dv) so left me with the original problem. So should I copy the dataview to a new datatable (which might then be in the correct sort order) and might allow use of the 'Distinct' method which (using columns 12 ans 11) would remove duplicates.

Comment: Hi Andrew - It turns out the question is still open - see my revised comment - but assuming I eventually tumble with help to the correct answer, my response should be to just check the answering post?